# Gulp Command Spams console

Tags: cmd, gulp

I added a package.json to my project, installed gulp via npm (global and local) and this is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    watch('src/css/**/*.css', function () {
        gulp.src('src/css/**/*.css')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    });
});
```

gulp-watch is also installed locally.

But when i now run `gulp`  in the command prompt it starts spamming the gulp command... My projects name is `boiler` (A frontend boilerplate).

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrDVs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled npm and gulp, which resolved my issue.